# Using the symstore to delete all pdb's older than X months

Tags: archive, symstore

I looked through the articles but couldn't find an answer to my question-

We have pdbs published to a server but are running out of space... we would like to properly unpublish/move/archive etc using the symstore so we don't effect the transaction id's and the way they were stored.

How can I specify to move/delete all pdb's older than X  months

I reviewed the command list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681378(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I think the [`AgeStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command, part of the debugging tools, was made specifically for this purpose. Something like

```
AgeStore \\symbolserver\symbols -days=90
```

would remove all symbols older than three months.

Answer (score 2):

The server.txt file inside the 000Admin folder is a CSV-format text file that has all the information you need.

You can parse this file and get the ID and date for each file stored.

If the date is older than X months, then issue a delete command for that ID.

Note that the delete command will lock and modify the server.txt file so I recommend you parse it completely, close it and only then iterate through the list while issuing the delete commands.

Comment: Alternatively, copy the server.txt file locally, and issue the delete commands while parsing the copy.